# delete rows with particular value in a column (R)?

Tags: r

I have a df with values like the following:

```
    head(df,n=5)
   Var1 Var2  timeLayer value
    1    1    1 2020-01-01    NA
    2    2    1 2020-01-01    NA
    3    3    1 2020-01-01    NA
    4    4    2 2020-01-02    NA
    5    5    2 2020-01-02    NA
```

I have a date variable 'diff' with the following entries:

```
head(as.Date(diff,origin="1970-01-01"))
[1] "2020-01-02" "2020-01-05" "2020-01-08" "2020-01-17" "2020-01-19" "2020-01-23"
```

what I want to achieve is delete all the rows in df data frame that have the diff values in timeLayer column.

```
     head(df,n=5)
   Var1 Var2  timeLayer value
    1    1    1 2020-01-01    NA
    2    2    1 2020-01-01    NA
    3    3    1 2020-01-01    NA
    6    6    3 2020-01-03    NA
    7    7    3 2020-01-03    NA
```

trying `rdf<-df[-c(diff)]` does not work. what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R using boolean masking. The idea is to create a logical vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values corresponding to the condition that you want to test, i.e. whether the value of `timeLayer` is in `diff`. You can then use that to subset your original data. Here is an example:

```r
df  <- read.table(text = "Var1 Var2  timeLayer value
    1    1    1 2020-01-01    NA
    2    2    1 2020-01-02    NA
    3    3    1 2020-01-03    NA
    4    4    2 2020-01-04    NA
    5    5    2 2020-01-05    NA", h = T)

diff  <- c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-03")

df$timeLayer %in% diff
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

You can then use these values to select which rows you want to keep. Note that here we use the `!` (not) prefix as we want to keep the values where `timeLayer` is not in `diff`:

```r
rdf <- df[!df$timeLayer %in% diff, ]

rdf
#   Var1 Var2  timeLayer value
# 1    1    1 2020-01-01    NA
# 4    4    2 2020-01-04    NA
# 5    5    2 2020-01-05    NA
```

#### dplyr approach

You can also do this in `dplyr` using `filter()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
    filter(!timeLayer %in% diff)
#   Var1 Var2  timeLayer value
# 1    1    1 2020-01-01    NA
# 4    4    2 2020-01-04    NA
# 5    5    2 2020-01-05    NA
```

#### data.table  approach

The syntax is similar to base R but we do not need to use the `df$` prefix when referring to a column name within square brackets:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[!timeLayer %in% diff,]
#    Var1 Var2  timeLayer value
# 1:    1    1 2020-01-01    NA
# 2:    4    2 2020-01-04    NA
# 3:    5    2 2020-01-05    NA
```